# Mask Scaling Factor from axis

Tags: pgfplots

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you remove the axis multiplier?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9803/how-do-you-remove-the-axis-multiplier)

I'd like to mask the scaling factor from my plot:

Here's an image

[image]

I marked it with two red circles.

How can I do this?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{bluerect/.style={fill=blue!20, semitransparent}}
\tikzset{redrect/.style={fill=red!20, semitransparent}}

\begin{axis}[
name=plot1,
scale only axis,
width=12cm,
height=4cm,
title=unkomprimiert,
ylabel=Echostärke,
xmin=0, xmax=70000,
xticklabels={,,},
ymin=-0.6, ymax=0.8]
\addplot[smooth] table {miles.csv};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
name=plot2,
at={($(plot1.south)+(0,-6cm)$)},anchor=south,
scale only axis,
width=12cm,
height=4cm,
title=komprimiert,
ylabel=Echostärke,
xmin=10000, xmax=80000,
xticklabels={,,},
ymin=-0.6, ymax=0.8]
\addplot[smooth] table {miles.csv};
\end{axis}

\draw[bluerect] (7cm, 0cm) rectangle (8.5cm, 4cm);
\draw[bluerect] (10.3cm, 0cm) rectangle (11.8cm, 4cm);
\draw[<->, >=stealth, black] (8.6cm, -1cm) -- (10.1cm, -1cm);
\draw (10.1cm, 0) -- (10.1cm, -1.1cm);

\draw[redrect] (5.3cm, -6cm) rectangle (6.8cm, -2cm);
\draw[redrect] (8.6cm, -6cm) rectangle (10.1cm, -2cm);
\draw (8.6cm, -2cm) -- (8.6cm, -0.9cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Hi Stefan, welcome to TeX.sx! You can remove the scaling factor using `scaled x ticks = false`. See [How do you remove the axis multiplier?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9803/pgfplot-setting-the-axis-wide-scientific-notation-tick-multiplier)

Comment: Jake, thank you! Sorry for reasking - this site already helped me a lot!

Comment: No problem at all. The old question wasn't very easy to find (I only renamed it after you asked your question).