# pgfplots using Time Series in .txt

Tags: pgfplots, dateplot

I have the following Time Series data

```
Date S
2010-01-11  7260
2010-01-12  7270
2010-01-13  7440
2010-01-14  7430
2010-01-15  7460
2010-01-18  7500
2010-01-19  7580
2010-01-20  7470
```

Where S is the name of the second column. The name of the file is VTB_S.txt. The second graph is from the VTB_F.txt file, which is identical to the VTB_S.txt.

I am trying to get a graph with the values of 'S' on the vertical axes, but it does not happening. With the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\definecolor{skyblue1}{rgb}{0.447,0.624,0.812}
\definecolor{scarletred1}{rgb}{0.937,0.161,0.161}
\pgfplotsset{width=12cm,compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
date coordinates in=x,
 x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
 xticklabel={\year},
 ylabel=Price,
 xlabel=Time,
 enlargelimits=0.10,
 legend columns=2,
]

\addplot[smooth, no markers, color=skyblue1]
  table [x=Date, y index=1] {VTB_S.txt};
\addplot[smooth, dashed, no markers, color=scarletred1]
  table [x=Date, y index=1] {VTB_F.txt};

 % both data files are in the following format:
 % Date S
 % 2010-01-11  7260
 % 2010-01-12  7270
 % 2010-01-13  7440
 % 2010-01-14  7430
 % 2010-01-15  7460
\legend{Spot, Future}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But I always get wrong values (0.1, 0,2, ... , 0.9) on y-axes. I presume that LaTeX scale all values in column 'S' to 1 and used scaled values. Could you please explain how to get the correct values on y-axes?

Hope the link works
[enter link description here][1]

```
Date S


2011-01-11  10410
2011-01-12  10930
2011-01-13  10800
2011-01-14  10910
2011-01-17  10910
2011-01-18  10920
2011-01-19  10910
2011-01-20  10780
2011-01-21  11100
2011-01-24  10920
2011-01-25  10890
2011-01-26  11070
2011-01-27  11060
2011-01-28  10900
2011-01-31  10700
2011-02-01  10620
2011-02-02  10280
2011-02-03  10230
2011-02-04  10220
2011-02-07  10120
2011-02-08  9650
2011-02-09  9690
2011-02-10  9340
2011-02-11  9460
2011-02-14  9510
2011-02-15  9530
2011-02-16  9890
2011-02-17  9750
2011-02-18  9600
2011-02-21  9560
2011-02-22  9530
2011-02-24  9490
2011-02-25  9860
2011-02-28  10120
2011-03-01  9804
2011-03-02  9744
2011-03-03  9760
2011-03-04  9655
2011-03-05  9783
2011-03-09  9767
2011-03-10  9410
2011-03-11  9428
2011-03-14  9265
2011-03-15  9140
2011-03-16  9071
2011-03-17  9247
2011-03-18  9330
2011-03-21  9455
2011-03-22  9400
2011-03-23  9519
2011-03-24  9729
2011-03-25  9815
2011-03-28  9962
2011-03-29  9796
2011-03-30  9933
2011-03-31  9870
2011-04-01  10015
2011-04-04  10030
2011-04-05  9870
2011-04-06  9945
2011-04-07  9741
2011-04-08  9852
2011-04-11  9887
2011-04-12  9618
2011-04-13  9630
2011-04-14  9540
2011-04-15  9517
2011-04-18  9205
2011-04-19  9298
2011-04-20  9391
2011-04-21  9276
2011-04-22  9499
2011-04-25  9296
2011-04-26  9330
2011-04-27  9109
2011-04-28  8940
2011-04-29  8860
2011-05-03  8590
2011-05-04  8295
2011-05-05  8480
2011-05-06  8700
2011-05-10  8565
2011-05-11  8461
2011-05-12  8271
2011-05-13  8400
2011-05-16  8260
2011-05-17  8333
2011-05-18  8402
2011-05-19  8366
2011-05-20  8275
2011-05-23  8086
2011-05-24  8351
2011-05-25  8583
2011-05-26  8503
2011-05-27  8690
2011-05-30  8599
2011-05-31  8680
2011-06-01  8600
2011-06-02  8699
2011-06-03  8445
2011-06-06  8440
2011-06-07  8537
2011-06-08  8514
2011-06-09  8722
2011-06-10  8881
2011-06-14  8820
2011-06-15  8820
2011-06-16  8835
2011-06-17  8661
2011-06-20  8434
2011-06-21  8535
2011-06-22  8414
2011-06-23  8159
2011-06-24  8224
2011-06-27  8311
2011-06-28  8240
2011-06-29  8580
2011-06-30  8596
2011-07-01  8777
2011-07-04  8684
2011-07-05  8500
2011-07-06  8280
2011-07-07  8401
2011-07-08  8265
2011-07-11  8306
2011-07-12  8275
2011-07-13  8285
2011-07-14  8324
2011-07-15  8457
2011-07-18  8333
2011-07-19  8534
2011-07-20  8560
2011-07-21  8799
2011-07-22  8624
2011-07-25  8526
2011-07-26  8500
2011-07-27  8546
2011-07-28  8514
2011-07-29  8323
2011-08-01  8456
2011-08-02  8380
2011-08-03  8090
2011-08-04  8019
2011-08-05  8011
2011-08-08  7710
2011-08-09  7665
2011-08-10  6969
2011-08-11  6910
2011-08-12  7200
2011-08-15  7347
2011-08-16  7171
2011-08-17  7262
2011-08-18  6832
2011-08-19  6800
2011-08-22  6921
2011-08-23  6882
2011-08-24  7180
2011-08-25  7128
2011-08-26  7307
2011-08-29  7600
2011-08-30  7592
2011-08-31  7501
2011-09-01  7630
2011-09-02  7408
2011-09-05  7239
2011-09-06  7409
2011-09-07  7541
2011-09-08  7548
2011-09-09  7462
2011-09-12  7310
2011-09-13  7437
2011-09-14  7630
2011-09-15  7676
2011-09-16  7630
2011-09-19  7690
2011-09-20  7795
2011-09-21  7668
2011-09-22  7138
2011-09-23  6600
2011-09-26  6653
2011-09-27  6881
2011-09-28  6698
2011-09-29  6893
2011-09-30  6697
2011-10-03  6596
2011-10-04  6111
2011-10-05  6039
2011-10-06  6389
2011-10-07  6625
2011-10-10  6795
2011-10-11  6569
2011-10-12  6659
2011-10-13  6521
2011-10-14  6703
2011-10-17  6596
2011-10-18  6595
2011-10-19  6595
2011-10-20  6507
2011-10-21  6783
2011-10-24  7135
2011-10-25  6992
2011-10-26  7097
2011-10-27  7240
2011-10-28  7415
2011-10-31  7337
2011-11-01  7064
2011-11-02  7191
2011-11-03  7336
2011-11-07  7405
2011-11-08  7475
2011-11-09  7166
2011-11-10  7290
2011-11-11  7210
2011-11-14  7180
2011-11-15  7145
2011-11-16  7037
2011-11-17  6908
2011-11-18  6800
2011-11-21  6324
2011-11-22  6375
2011-11-23  6270
2011-11-24  6150
2011-11-25  6200
2011-11-28  6444
2011-11-29  6400
2011-11-30  6740
2011-12-01  6876
2011-12-02  7064
2011-12-05  7150
2011-12-06  6740
2011-12-07  6667
2011-12-08  6679
2011-12-09  6310
2011-12-12  6077
2011-12-13  6199
2011-12-14  6160
2011-12-15  6221
2011-12-16  6299
2011-12-19  6213
2011-12-20  6330
2011-12-21  6105
2011-12-22  6070
2011-12-23  5952
2011-12-26  6029
2011-12-27  5999
2011-12-28  5929
2011-12-29  5798
2011-12-30  5870
2012-01-03  6160
2012-01-04  6130
2012-01-05  6016
2012-01-06  6038
2012-01-09  6060
2012-01-10  6245
2012-01-11  6234
2012-01-12  6316
2012-01-13  6441
2012-01-16  6435
2012-01-17  6612
2012-01-18  6646
2012-01-19  6626
2012-01-20  6501
2012-01-23  6579
2012-01-24  6546
2012-01-25  6761
2012-01-26  7127
2012-01-27  7061
2012-01-30  6985
2012-01-31  7053
2012-02-01  7173
2012-02-02  7260
2012-02-03  7307
2012-02-06  7247
2012-02-07  7106
2012-02-08  7000
2012-02-09  6891
2012-02-10  6761
2012-02-13  7071
2012-02-14  7100
2012-02-15  7195
2012-02-16  7094
2012-02-17  7099
2012-02-20  7139
2012-02-21  7040
2012-02-22  6927
2012-02-24  7205
2012-02-27  7297
2012-02-28  7137
2012-02-29  7247
2012-03-01  7287
2012-03-02  7284
2012-03-05  7394
2012-03-06  7043
2012-03-07  7091
2012-03-11  7220
2012-03-12  7130
2012-03-13  7190
2012-03-14  7331
2012-03-15  7312
2012-03-16  7367
2012-03-19  7227
2012-03-20  6930
2012-03-21  6890
2012-03-22  6755
2012-03-23  6838
2012-03-26  7055
2012-03-27  6950
2012-03-28  6750
2012-03-29  6560
2012-03-30  6695
2012-04-02  6827
2012-04-03  6978
2012-04-04  6746
2012-04-05  6827
2012-04-06  6707
2012-04-09  6772
2012-04-10  6668
2012-04-11  6684
2012-04-12  6633
2012-04-13  6580
2012-04-16  6404
2012-04-17  6395
2012-04-18  6391
2012-04-19  6490
2012-04-20  6571
2012-04-23  6303
2012-04-24  6350
2012-04-25  6518
2012-04-26  6313
2012-04-27  6329
2012-04-28  6320
2012-05-02  6206
2012-05-03  6194
2012-05-04  5945
2012-05-05  5901
2012-05-07  5788
2012-05-08  5718
2012-05-10  5880
2012-05-11  5833
2012-05-12  5889
2012-05-14  5648
2012-05-15  5672
2012-05-16  5700
2012-05-17  5450
2012-05-18  5430
2012-05-21  5591
2012-05-22  5669
2012-05-23  5334
2012-05-24  5434
2012-05-25  5410
2012-05-28  5395
2012-05-29  5563
2012-05-30  5352
2012-05-31  5307
2012-06-01  5159
2012-06-04  5212
2012-06-05  5240
2012-06-06  5340
2012-06-07  5524
2012-06-08  5487
2012-06-09  5525
2012-06-13  5591
2012-06-14  5560
2012-06-15  5650
2012-06-18  5759
2012-06-19  5830
2012-06-20  5688
2012-06-21  5690
2012-06-22  5575
2012-06-25  5479
2012-06-26  5505
2012-06-27  5598
2012-06-28  5371
2012-06-29  5707
2012-07-02  5876
2012-07-03  6086
2012-07-04  6026
2012-07-05  5860
2012-07-06  5625
2012-07-09  5650
2012-07-10  5713
2012-07-11  5550
2012-07-12  5425
2012-07-13  5560
2012-07-16  5560
2012-07-17  5536
2012-07-18  5519
2012-07-19  5512
2012-07-20  5395
2012-07-23  5140
2012-07-24  5121
2012-07-25  5107
2012-07-26  5185
2012-07-27  5240
2012-07-30  5361
2012-07-31  5303
2012-08-01  5375
2012-08-02  5350
2012-08-03  5490
2012-08-06  5709
2012-08-07  5810
2012-08-08  5740
2012-08-09  5744
2012-08-10  5661
2012-08-13  5701
2012-08-14  5703
2012-08-15  5623
2012-08-16  5618
2012-08-17  5586
2012-08-20  5504
2012-08-21  5621
2012-08-22  5562
2012-08-23  5572
2012-08-24  5582
2012-08-27  5564
2012-08-28  5568
2012-08-29  5437
2012-08-30  5323
2012-08-31  5340
2012-09-03  5379
2012-09-04  5325
2012-09-05  5265
2012-09-06  5450
2012-09-07  5669
2012-09-10  5673
2012-09-11  5740
2012-09-12  5711
2012-09-13  5657
2012-09-14  6010
2012-09-17  5915
2012-09-18  5770
2012-09-19  5602
2012-09-20  5562
2012-09-21  5640
2012-09-24  5589
2012-09-25  5550
2012-09-26  5342
2012-09-27  5391
2012-09-28  5307
2012-10-01  5381
2012-10-02  5444
2012-10-03  5448
2012-10-04  5407
2012-10-05  5492
2012-10-08  5452
2012-10-09  5421
2012-10-10  5393
2012-10-11  5450
2012-10-12  5390
2012-10-15  5379
2012-10-16  5410
2012-10-17  5520
2012-10-18  5500
2012-10-19  5407
2012-10-22  5452
2012-10-23  5392
2012-10-24  5403
2012-10-25  5474
2012-10-26  5570
2012-10-29  5564
2012-10-30  5495
2012-10-31  5450
2012-11-01  5460
2012-11-02  5415
2012-11-06  5498
2012-11-07  5413
2012-11-08  5349
2012-11-09  5272
2012-11-12  5259
2012-11-13  5130
2012-11-14  5079
2012-11-15  5102
2012-11-16  5174
2012-11-19  5200
2012-11-20  5190
2012-11-21  5206
2012-11-22  5220
2012-11-23  5271
2012-11-26  5240
2012-11-27  5178
2012-11-28  5120
2012-11-29  5161
2012-11-30  5193
2012-12-03  5262
2012-12-04  5204
2012-12-05  5230
2012-12-06  5255
2012-12-07  5254
2012-12-10  5233
2012-12-11  5266
2012-12-12  5360
2012-12-13  5388
2012-12-14  5391
2012-12-17  5404
2012-12-18  5491
2012-12-19  5487
2012-12-20  5449
2012-12-21  5436
2012-12-24  5401
2012-12-25  5410
2012-12-26  5419
2012-12-27  5422
2012-12-28  5359
2013-01-08  5492
2013-01-09  5479
2013-01-10  5524
2013-01-11  5754
2013-01-14  5775
2013-01-15  5740
2013-01-16  5771
2013-01-17  5775
2013-01-18  5823
2013-01-21  5833
2013-01-22  5936
2013-01-23  5947
2013-01-24  5899
2013-01-25  5914
2013-01-28  5929
2013-01-29  5800
2013-01-30  5609
2013-01-31  5582
2013-02-01  5615
2013-02-04  5508
2013-02-05  5530
2013-02-06  5402
2013-02-07  5422
2013-02-08  5363
2013-02-11  5310
2013-02-12  5280
2013-02-13  5564
2013-02-14  5647
2013-02-15  5599
2013-02-18  5599
2013-02-19  5649
2013-02-20  5689
2013-02-21  5468
2013-02-22  5435
2013-02-25  5489
2013-02-26  5478
2013-02-27  5515
2013-02-28  5588
2013-03-01  5571
2013-03-04  5550
2013-03-05  5623
2013-03-06  5581
2013-03-07  5581
2013-03-11  5588
2013-03-12  5580
2013-03-13  5575
2013-03-14  5541
2013-03-15  5535
2013-03-18  5237
2013-03-19  5148
2013-03-20  5238
2013-03-21  5168
2013-03-22  5120
2013-03-25  5029
2013-03-26  4900
2013-03-27  4825
2013-03-28  4975
2013-03-29  4970
2013-04-01  4950
2013-04-02  4923
2013-04-03  4839
2013-04-04  4730
2013-04-05  4680
2013-04-08  4788
2013-04-09  4900
2013-04-10  4827
2013-04-11  4781
2013-04-12  4730
2013-04-15  4573
2013-04-16  4558
2013-04-17  4380
2013-04-18  4342
2013-04-19  4360
2013-04-22  4446
2013-04-23  4545
2013-04-24  4570
2013-04-25  4575
2013-04-26  4529
2013-04-29  4705
2013-04-30  4929
2013-05-02  4834
2013-05-03  4890
2013-05-06  4946
2013-05-07  5051
2013-05-08  5091
2013-05-10  4961
2013-05-13  4785
2013-05-14  4600
2013-05-15  4541
2013-05-16  4414
2013-05-17  4499
2013-05-20  4648
2013-05-21  4820
2013-05-22  4985
2013-05-23  4778
2013-05-24  4686
2013-05-27  4664
2013-05-28  4725
2013-05-29  4600
2013-05-30  4554
2013-05-31  4600
2013-06-03  4662
2013-06-04  4798
2013-06-05  4718
2013-06-06  4660
```

and

```
Date F


2011-01-11  10401
2011-01-12  10917
2011-01-13  10844
2011-01-14  10916
2011-01-17  10925
2011-01-18  10915
2011-01-19  10910
2011-01-20  10791
2011-01-21  11091
2011-01-24  10950
2011-01-25  10910
2011-01-26  11090
2011-01-27  11050
2011-01-28  10880
2011-01-31  10700
2011-02-01  10630
2011-02-02  10247
2011-02-03  10143
2011-02-04  9928
2011-02-07  9900
2011-02-08  9550
2011-02-09  9671
2011-02-10  9257
2011-02-11  9367
2011-02-14  9466
2011-02-15  9521
2011-02-16  9884
2011-02-17  9748
2011-02-18  9600
2011-02-21  9590
2011-02-22  9525
2011-02-24  9518
2011-02-25  9845
2011-02-28  10097
2011-03-01  9777
2011-03-02  9734
2011-03-03  9767
2011-03-04  9650
2011-03-05  9752
2011-03-09  9757
2011-03-10  9448
2011-03-11  9431
2011-03-14  9298
2011-03-15  9341
2011-03-16  9171
2011-03-17  9123
2011-03-18  9296
2011-03-21  9331
2011-03-22  9464
2011-03-23  9397
2011-03-24  9528
2011-03-25  9724
2011-03-28  9811
2011-03-29  9954
2011-03-30  9805
2011-03-31  9946
2011-04-01  9881
2011-04-04  10033
2011-04-05  10045
2011-04-06  9875
2011-04-07  9925
2011-04-08  9738
2011-04-11  9827
2011-04-12  9863
2011-04-13  9570
2011-04-14  9605
2011-04-15  9482
2011-04-18  9465
2011-04-19  9170
2011-04-20  9249
2011-04-21  9349
2011-04-22  9280
2011-04-25  9528
2011-04-26  9335
2011-04-27  9304
2011-04-28  9139
2011-04-29  8960
2011-05-03  8874
2011-05-04  8622
2011-05-05  8311
2011-05-06  8494
2011-05-10  8671
2011-05-11  8581
2011-05-12  8516
2011-05-13  8272
2011-05-16  8416
2011-05-17  8281
2011-05-18  8342
2011-05-19  8423
2011-05-20  8388
2011-05-23  8289
2011-05-24  8110
2011-05-25  8358
2011-05-26  8582
2011-05-27  8527
2011-05-30  8703
2011-05-31  8623
2011-06-01  8690
2011-06-02  8634
2011-06-03  8699
2011-06-06  8460
2011-06-07  8446
2011-06-08  8546
2011-06-09  8530
2011-06-10  8740
2011-06-14  8878
2011-06-15  8830
2011-06-16  8914
2011-06-17  8748
2011-06-20  8530
2011-06-21  8625
2011-06-22  8507
2011-06-23  8242
2011-06-24  8310
2011-06-27  8379
2011-06-28  8316
2011-06-29  8641
2011-06-30  8656
2011-07-01  8826
2011-07-04  8742
2011-07-05  8564
2011-07-06  8350
2011-07-07  8450
2011-07-08  8313
2011-07-11  8352
2011-07-12  8313
2011-07-13  8329
2011-07-14  8365
2011-07-15  8512
2011-07-18  8389
2011-07-19  8588
2011-07-20  8624
2011-07-21  8836
2011-07-22  8673
2011-07-25  8545
2011-07-26  8529
2011-07-27  8584
2011-07-28  8553
2011-07-29  8369
2011-08-01  8491
2011-08-02  8410
2011-08-03  8114
2011-08-04  8050
2011-08-05  8077
2011-08-08  7747
2011-08-09  7649
2011-08-10  6966
2011-08-11  6966
2011-08-12  7237
2011-08-15  7369
2011-08-16  7200
2011-08-17  7277
2011-08-18  6856
2011-08-19  6817
2011-08-22  6937
2011-08-23  6900
2011-08-24  7201
2011-08-25  7138
2011-08-26  7309
2011-08-29  7608
2011-08-30  7611
2011-08-31  7507
2011-09-01  7626
2011-09-02  7420
2011-09-05  7242
2011-09-06  7395
2011-09-07  7551
2011-09-08  7545
2011-09-09  7475
2011-09-12  7306
2011-09-13  7424
2011-09-14  7626
2011-09-15  7770
2011-09-16  7730
2011-09-19  7750
2011-09-20  7889
2011-09-21  7745
2011-09-22  7177
2011-09-23  6650
2011-09-26  6726
2011-09-27  6939
2011-09-28  6757
2011-09-29  6964
2011-09-30  6734
2011-10-03  6629
2011-10-04  6170
2011-10-05  6059
2011-10-06  6424
2011-10-07  6701
2011-10-10  6856
2011-10-11  6626
2011-10-12  6715
2011-10-13  6557
2011-10-14  6795
2011-10-17  6602
2011-10-18  6635
2011-10-19  6641
2011-10-20  6569
2011-10-21  6825
2011-10-24  7170
2011-10-25  7017
2011-10-26  7131
2011-10-27  7280
2011-10-28  7450
2011-10-31  7374
2011-11-01  7117
2011-11-02  7219
2011-11-03  7370
2011-11-07  7437
2011-11-08  7500
2011-11-09  7202
2011-11-10  7310
2011-11-11  7230
2011-11-14  7201
2011-11-15  7165
2011-11-16  7060
2011-11-17  6933
2011-11-18  6809
2011-11-21  6339
2011-11-22  6387
2011-11-23  6281
2011-11-24  6159
2011-11-25  6222
2011-11-28  6460
2011-11-29  6410
2011-11-30  6786
2011-12-01  6875
2011-12-02  7039
2011-12-05  7161
2011-12-06  6743
2011-12-07  6699
2011-12-08  6679
2011-12-09  6305
2011-12-12  6087
2011-12-13  6197
2011-12-14  6127
2011-12-15  6300
2011-12-16  6360
2011-12-19  6271
2011-12-20  6388
2011-12-21  6168
2011-12-22  6130
2011-12-23  6004
2011-12-26  6089
2011-12-27  6063
2011-12-28  5981
2011-12-29  5850
2011-12-30  5936
2012-01-03  6209
2012-01-04  6176
2012-01-05  6073
2012-01-06  6114
2012-01-09  6091
2012-01-10  6290
2012-01-11  6268
2012-01-12  6342
2012-01-13  6500
2012-01-16  6500
2012-01-17  6673
2012-01-18  6689
2012-01-19  6675
2012-01-20  6556
2012-01-23  6627
2012-01-24  6597
2012-01-25  6803
2012-01-26  7175
2012-01-27  7107
2012-01-30  7031
2012-01-31  7113
2012-02-01  7224
2012-02-02  7317
2012-02-03  7356
2012-02-06  7290
2012-02-07  7149
2012-02-08  7029
2012-02-09  6932
2012-02-10  6800
2012-02-13  7102
2012-02-14  7123
2012-02-15  7227
2012-02-16  7134
2012-02-17  7130
2012-02-20  7173
2012-02-21  7072
2012-02-22  6967
2012-02-24  7231
2012-02-27  7327
2012-02-28  7164
2012-02-29  7270
2012-03-01  7321
2012-03-02  7300
2012-03-05  7412
2012-03-06  7056
2012-03-07  7090
2012-03-11  7234
2012-03-12  7144
2012-03-13  7197
2012-03-14  7320
2012-03-15  7324
2012-03-16  7350
2012-03-19  7226
2012-03-20  6935
2012-03-21  6882
2012-03-22  6759
2012-03-23  6838
2012-03-26  7051
2012-03-27  6953
2012-03-28  6753
2012-03-29  6559
2012-03-30  6695
2012-04-02  6832
2012-04-03  6971
2012-04-04  6745
2012-04-05  6801
2012-04-06  6693
2012-04-09  6757
2012-04-10  6674
2012-04-11  6685
2012-04-12  6623
2012-04-13  6568
2012-04-16  6390
2012-04-17  6370
2012-04-18  6351
2012-04-19  6452
2012-04-20  6541
2012-04-23  6240
2012-04-24  6305
2012-04-25  6493
2012-04-26  6309
2012-04-27  6375
2012-04-28  6369
2012-05-02  6259
2012-05-03  6244
2012-05-04  5985
2012-05-05  5930
2012-05-07  5815
2012-05-08  5749
2012-05-10  5908
2012-05-11  5865
2012-05-12  5915
2012-05-14  5670
2012-05-15  5698
2012-05-16  5713
2012-05-17  5480
2012-05-18  5460
2012-05-21  5607
2012-05-22  5688
2012-05-23  5368
2012-05-24  5460
2012-05-25  5439
2012-05-28  5408
2012-05-29  5572
2012-05-30  5354
2012-05-31  5310
2012-06-01  5164
2012-06-04  5222
2012-06-05  5245
2012-06-06  5345
2012-06-07  5538
2012-06-08  5491
2012-06-09  5523
2012-06-13  5584
2012-06-14  5560
2012-06-15  5720
2012-06-18  5840
2012-06-19  5914
2012-06-20  5780
2012-06-21  5772
2012-06-22  5645
2012-06-25  5552
2012-06-26  5584
2012-06-27  5674
2012-06-28  5454
2012-06-29  5791
2012-07-02  5960
2012-07-03  6155
2012-07-04  6108
2012-07-05  5924
2012-07-06  5682
2012-07-09  5707
2012-07-10  5780
2012-07-11  5610
2012-07-12  5483
2012-07-13  5628
2012-07-16  5622
2012-07-17  5597
2012-07-18  5573
2012-07-19  5575
2012-07-20  5455
2012-07-23  5193
2012-07-24  5167
2012-07-25  5161
2012-07-26  5231
2012-07-27  5288
2012-07-30  5407
2012-07-31  5348
2012-08-01  5418
2012-08-02  5394
2012-08-03  5525
2012-08-06  5744
2012-08-07  5846
2012-08-08  5783
2012-08-09  5777
2012-08-10  5697
2012-08-13  5734
2012-08-14  5735
2012-08-15  5658
2012-08-16  5645
2012-08-17  5615
2012-08-20  5535
2012-08-21  5647
2012-08-22  5594
2012-08-23  5596
2012-08-24  5602
2012-08-27  5588
2012-08-28  5593
2012-08-29  5457
2012-08-30  5333
2012-08-31  5359
2012-09-03  5397
2012-09-04  5337
2012-09-05  5276
2012-09-06  5470
2012-09-07  5687
2012-09-10  5684
2012-09-11  5745
2012-09-12  5722
2012-09-13  5659
2012-09-14  6003
2012-09-17  6009
2012-09-18  5855
2012-09-19  5689
2012-09-20  5644
2012-09-21  5724
2012-09-24  5660
2012-09-25  5621
2012-09-26  5408
2012-09-27  5463
2012-09-28  5357
2012-10-01  5450
2012-10-02  5506
2012-10-03  5520
2012-10-04  5469
2012-10-05  5564
2012-10-08  5513
2012-10-09  5478
2012-10-10  5442
2012-10-11  5508
2012-10-12  5439
2012-10-15  5431
2012-10-16  5465
2012-10-17  5572
2012-10-18  5557
2012-10-19  5457
2012-10-22  5500
2012-10-23  5436
2012-10-24  5441
2012-10-25  5515
2012-10-26  5616
2012-10-29  5607
2012-10-30  5550
2012-10-31  5496
2012-11-01  5499
2012-11-02  5456
2012-11-06  5540
2012-11-07  5450
2012-11-08  5388
2012-11-09  5308
2012-11-12  5291
2012-11-13  5158
2012-11-14  5102
2012-11-15  5131
2012-11-16  5202
2012-11-19  5222
2012-11-20  5217
2012-11-21  5220
2012-11-22  5240
2012-11-23  5290
2012-11-26  5259
2012-11-27  5198
2012-11-28  5140
2012-11-29  5182
2012-11-30  5229
2012-12-03  5279
2012-12-04  5215
2012-12-05  5239
2012-12-06  5268
2012-12-07  5268
2012-12-10  5242
2012-12-11  5292
2012-12-12  5365
2012-12-13  5390
2012-12-14  5387
2012-12-17  5487
2012-12-18  5589
2012-12-19  5577
2012-12-20  5522
2012-12-21  5520
2012-12-24  5495
2012-12-25  5499
2012-12-26  5499
2012-12-27  5487
2012-12-28  5413
2013-01-08  5556
2013-01-09  5540
2013-01-10  5571
2013-01-11  5816
2013-01-14  5825
2013-01-15  5792
2013-01-16  5821
2013-01-17  5825
2013-01-18  5876
2013-01-21  5887
2013-01-22  5990
2013-01-23  5994
2013-01-24  5952
2013-01-25  5957
2013-01-28  5974
2013-01-29  5850
2013-01-30  5653
2013-01-31  5638
2013-02-01  5661
2013-02-04  5553
2013-02-05  5574
2013-02-06  5450
2013-02-07  5465
2013-02-08  5408
2013-02-11  5347
2013-02-12  5310
2013-02-13  5588
2013-02-14  5674
2013-02-15  5632
2013-02-18  5625
2013-02-19  5672
2013-02-20  5710
2013-02-21  5485
2013-02-22  5457
2013-02-25  5504
2013-02-26  5500
2013-02-27  5529
2013-02-28  5603
2013-03-01  5584
2013-03-04  5574
2013-03-05  5635
2013-03-06  5593
2013-03-07  5586
2013-03-11  5591
2013-03-12  5582
2013-03-13  5585
2013-03-14  5533
2013-03-15  5573
2013-03-18  5271
2013-03-19  5147
2013-03-20  5239
2013-03-21  5165
2013-03-22  5118
2013-03-25  4987
2013-03-26  4880
2013-03-27  4810
2013-03-28  4951
2013-03-29  4940
2013-04-01  4897
2013-04-02  4899
2013-04-03  4825
2013-04-04  4715
2013-04-05  4658
2013-04-08  4767
2013-04-09  4864
2013-04-10  4789
2013-04-11  4742
2013-04-12  4681
2013-04-15  4537
2013-04-16  4513
2013-04-17  4344
2013-04-18  4302
2013-04-19  4317
2013-04-22  4370
2013-04-23  4473
2013-04-24  4502
2013-04-25  4461
2013-04-26  4448
2013-04-29  4611
2013-04-30  4848
2013-05-02  4762
2013-05-03  4806
2013-05-06  4843
2013-05-07  4960
2013-05-08  4970
2013-05-10  4875
2013-05-13  4727
2013-05-14  4635
2013-05-15  4569
2013-05-16  4444
2013-05-17  4536
2013-05-20  4681
2013-05-21  4827
2013-05-22  5008
2013-05-23  4798
2013-05-24  4715
2013-05-27  4695
2013-05-28  4751
2013-05-29  4624
2013-05-30  4582
2013-05-31  4620
2013-06-03  4684
2013-06-04  4805
2013-06-05  4729
2013-06-06  4667
```

Finally the correct code looks like

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\definecolor{skyblue1}{rgb}{0.447,0.624,0.812}
\definecolor{scarletred1}{rgb}{0.937,0.161,0.161}
\pgfplotsset{width=12cm,compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
 height=6cm, %set height
 width=\textwidth, %set width
 date coordinates in=x,
 x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
 xticklabel={\year},
 scaled y ticks = false,
 y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/1000 sep = \thinspace},
 ylabel=Price per 1 LoT (RUR),
 enlargelimits=0.08,  %--scale of inside lines--
 legend columns=2,  %---# of colums in the legend--
 date ZERO=2010-01-11  %--helps to numerate 2010-2011-2012--
]

\addplot[smooth, no markers, color=skyblue1, mark=none, domain=2010:2015]
  table [x=Date, y index=1] {VTB_S.log};
\addplot[smooth, dashed, no markers, color=scarletred1, mark=none, domain=2010:2015]
  table [x=Date, y index=1] {VTB_F.log};

 % both data files are in the following format:
 % date commits
 % 2011-07-01 3000
 % 2011-08-01 3020
 % 2011-09-01 3030
 % [...]
\legend{Spot, Future}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works fine for me, I get unscaled values. Could you edit your question to include the `.log` file?

Comment: Link for the .txt and .log files edited.

Comment: Could you upload it somewhere that allows anonymous access? Ideally, if the text isn't too long, you can just post it as a code block directly in the question.

Comment: I tried ones more, my LaTeX gives me scaled values again.

Comment: Ah yes, the labels  are indeed scaled because there are some large values in your data. There should be an axis multiplier at the top of the plot. To disable the scaling of the labels, see [How do you remove the axis multiplier?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9803/how-do-you-remove-the-axis-multiplier).

Comment: I have seen your post, but I am sort of a beginner to LaTeX, so if you don't mind, could you please provide the correct code?

Comment: I finally managed to do it, but anyway, Jake, you are awesome. You really helped!!!

Comment: @user51031: Glad it worked! If you don't mind, could you post the corrected code as an answer and accept it? That way, this question will be closed?

Comment: @user51031: Thanks for the edit, but it would be best if you put it into an answer (not in the question).

Comment: @Jake could you explain how to do that? I could also post a picture that I got from the code.

Comment: If you scroll down on this page, there should be a text entry  field marked "Your Answer".