# Usage of /pgf/number format/cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to fix the amount of digits the colorbar has, because the plot is shrinking in size and I wish to animate this plot, so a fixed height and width is mandatory. I still want LaTeX to do the calculations to maximize the size of the final product, so I still used `\textheight` and `\linewidth` (amongst others) for dimensions.

I've used `/pgf/number format/cd.` in other contexts with the same syntax, but in this case it yields error messages, related to about every single value I didn't set explicitly.

The intended effect is to have a set amount of digits in the colorbar, so that the graph doesn't appear to "move".

[image: http://i.imgur.com/SnxptGO.png?1]

(The color bar has some weird term `\cdot10^{-2}` floating above it. I want to get rid of this and I believe this will make the dimension `\linewidth` suffice to have a fixed width for the graph at any value for `\ik` smaller than 240.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{geometry}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
%\usepackage{animate}
%\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\newcommand{\dfa}{3}
\newcommand{\dfb}{9}
\newcommand{\ik}{240}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={gamma(\z)=
    2.506628274631*sqrt(1/\z)+0.20888568*(1/\z)^(1.5)+0.00870357*(1/\z)^(2.5)-(174.2106599*(1/\z)^(3.5))/25920-
    (715.6423511*(1/\z)^(4.5))/1244160)*exp((-ln(1/\z)-1)*\z;},
    declare function={beta(\x,\y)=(gamma(\x) * gamma(\y)) / (gamma(\x + \y));},
    declare function={threedf(\value)= (x^(x/2)*y^(y/2)*\value^(y/2 -1)*(x + y*\value)^(-.5*x -.5*y))/beta(y/2,x/2);},
        ]
\begin{axis}[
    colormap={mycolormap}{color(0cm)=(white); color(1cm)=(blue!75!red)},
    colormap name=mycolormap,
%    width=.99\linewidth-\marginparwidth-2\tabcolsep,
    height=.49\textheight,
    view={150}{45},
    enlargelimits=false,
    grid=major,
    domain=.5:10.5,
    y domain=.5:10.5,
    xmin = -.5, xmax = 11.5,
    ymin = -.5, ymax = 11.5,
    zmin = 0, zmax = 1,
    samples=11,
    xlabel=$df_1$,
    ylabel=$df_2$,
    zlabel=$F$,
    colorbar,
    colorbar style={
        at={(1.05,0)},
        anchor=south west,
        height=0.25*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/parent axis height},
%        title={$P(x_1,x_2)$},
        every tick label/.append style = 
        {/pgf/number format/.cd,
           precision = 2, 
           fixed zerofill,
           fixed, use comma,
          },} 
]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\result}{((\ik/53+.6)^2+(ln(\ik/53+.6)^2+1.5))/5};
%\path[name path=line] (axis cs:\dfa,\dfb,0) -- (axis cs:\dfa,\dfb,1);
\addplot3 [surf] {threedf(\result)};
\addlegendentry {$x = \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=3]{\result}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After you've set all your `number format` styles, you need to reset the key directory to the one you were in when you called `/pgf/number format/.cd`, in this case that's `/tikz/.cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{geometry}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
%\usepackage{animate}
%\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\newcommand{\dfa}{3}
\newcommand{\dfb}{9}
\newcommand{\ik}{240}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={gamma(\z)=
    2.506628274631*sqrt(1/\z)+0.20888568*(1/\z)^(1.5)+0.00870357*(1/\z)^(2.5)-(174.2106599*(1/\z)^(3.5))/25920-
    (715.6423511*(1/\z)^(4.5))/1244160)*exp((-ln(1/\z)-1)*\z;},
    declare function={beta(\x,\y)=(gamma(\x) * gamma(\y)) / (gamma(\x + \y));},
    declare function={threedf(\value)= (x^(x/2)*y^(y/2)*\value^(y/2 -1)*(x + y*\value)^(-.5*x -.5*y))/beta(y/2,x/2);},
        ]
\begin{axis}[
    colormap={mycolormap}{color(0cm)=(white); color(1cm)=(blue!75!red)},
    colormap name=mycolormap,
%    width=.99\linewidth-\marginparwidth-2\tabcolsep,
    height=.49\textheight,
    view={150}{45},
    enlargelimits=false,
    grid=major,
    domain=.5:10.5,
    y domain=.5:10.5,
    xmin = -.5, xmax = 11.5,
    ymin = -.5, ymax = 11.5,
    zmin = 0, zmax = 1,
    samples=11,
    xlabel=$df_1$,
    ylabel=$df_2$,
    zlabel=$F$,
    colorbar,
    colorbar style={
        at={(1.05,0)},
        anchor=south west,
        height=0.25*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/parent axis height},
%        title={$P(x_1,x_2)$},
        every tick label/.append style = 
        {/pgf/number format/.cd,
           precision = 2, 
           fixed zerofill,
           fixed, use comma,
         /tikz/.cd
          }
    } 
]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\result}{((\ik/53+.6)^2+(ln(\ik/53+.6)^2+1.5))/5};
%\path[name path=line] (axis cs:\dfa,\dfb,0) -- (axis cs:\dfa,\dfb,1);
\addplot3 [surf] {threedf(\result)};
\addlegendentry {$x = \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=3]{\result}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This got rid of the errors. But it didn't get rid of the `\cdot10^{-2}` that keeps appearing about the color bar. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Add `scaled y ticks=false` to the `colorbar style` options (see [How do you remove the axis multiplier?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9803/how-do-you-remove-the-axis-multiplier))