# Tikz bar chart example without power

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to use Tikz bar chart, but want to avoid showing it as 1.8*10^5. How can i do it?

```
% Bar charts
% Author: Stefan Kottwitz
% https://www.packtpub.com/hardware-and-creative/latex-cookbook
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title  = Contributions per category
                      at LaTeX-Community.org,
xbar,
y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
axis x line       = none,
tickwidth         = 0pt,
enlarge y limits  = 0.2,
enlarge x limits  = 0.02,
symbolic y coords = {LaTeX, Tools, Distributions, Editors},
nodes near coords,
]
\addplot coordinates { (180000,LaTeX)         (190000,Tools)
                     (2193,Distributions)  (11106,Editors) };
\addplot coordinates { (14320,LaTeX)         (1615,Tools)
                     (560,Distributions)   (3075,Editors)  };
\legend{Topics, Posts}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi busprom, welcome to the site! I think this might be a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9803/2552