# Problem with histogram axis y

Tags: graphics

I have a problem with my histogram. My y-axis is not in format I want. I want y-min = 0 and y-max = 12000 but my graphic is expressed in a power element.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[A4,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfig}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\begin{axis}[ybar,ymin=0.0,ymax=12000.0, 
             height=8cm,
             ymajorgrids=true,
             ylabel={Risposte},
             symbolic x coords={
               $18-30$, $31-40$, $41-50$, $50-100$},
             xtick=data, nodes near coords,
             xlabel={Anni},
             nodes near coords align={vertical},
             xtick pos=left]
\addplot [fill=blue,draw=black, ball color=blue] coordinates{
   ($18-30$,1411)($31-40$,2486) ($41-50$,4258) ($50-100$,10841)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

thanks[image]

Comment: Have you tried to add as options `scaled y ticks = false` and `y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed}`. Specifically the second part should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question is already answered [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9803/how-do-you-remove-the-axis-multiplier) but since I still cannot comment, I'll answer it. As stated in the [PGFplots Manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf) using the axis Option `scaled y ticks = false` solves this issue. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\begin{axis}[ybar, ymin=0.0, ymax=12000.0, ymajorgrids=true, ylabel={Risposte},
     scaled y ticks = false,
     xtick=data, xlabel={Anni}, xtick pos=left,
         symbolic x coords={ $18-30$, $31-40$, $41-50$, $50-100$}, 
         nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={vertical}, height=8cm]
\addplot [fill=blue,draw=black, ball color=blue] coordinates{ ($18-30$,1411)($31-40$,2486) ($41-50$,4258) ($50-100$,10841)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No problem! But if it is correct you can mark the answer as "accepted answer", that's the best way to say thank you in the TeX.sx community.