# Get rid of values

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I need to get rid of that`.10^-3` and instead show the actual number, i.e. 0.003:
[image]

How can I do that? I also would like to use the style of the markers that you see in this picture:

[image]

CODE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
%\pgfplotsset{}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}



\begin{figure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ 
        width=\linewidth,
        line width=0.5,
        grid=major, % Display a grid
        tick label style={font={\tiny }},
        legend style={nodes={scale=0.6, transform shape}},
        label style={font={\tiny }},
        legend image post style={},
        grid style={white},
        xlabel={$\gamma{1}$},
        ylabel={RMSE},
        y tick label style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=2
        },
        legend style={at={(1,0.75)}, anchor=north east,  draw=none, fill=none},
        ]

        \addplot[mark=oplus*,blue] coordinates
        {(0.00,1.1257) (0.001, 0.9556) (0.002,0.9449) (0.003,0.9415) (0.004,0.9399)(0.005, 0.9398) (0.006,0.9396) (0.007,0.9397) (0.008,0.9398) 

        };
        \addlegendentry{Error }

        %       \addplot[mark=*,black] coordinates
        %       {     (2, 0.9174) (4,0.8977) (6,0.8845) (8,0.8803) (10,0.8683)(12, 0.8606) (14, 0.8524) (16,0.8460) (18,0.8391) (20,0.8326) (22,0.8262) (24,0.8199) (26,0.8141)
        %           (28,0.8093)(30,0.8018)(32,0.7987)(34,0.7924)(36,0.7874)(38,0.7819) (40,0.7775)(42,0.7724)(44,0.7674)(46,0.7630) (48,0.7584) (50,0.7543)

        %       };
        %       \addlegendentry{$\gamma{1}$}
        \end{axis}

        \end{tikzpicture}

        \subcaption{blabla}
        \label{sub111}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ 
        width=\linewidth,
        line width=0.5,
        grid=major, % Display a grid
        tick label style={font={\tiny}},
        legend style={nodes={scale=0.6, transform shape}},
        label style={font={\tiny }},
        legend image post style={},
        grid style={white},
        xlabel={ $\lambda_{1}$},
        ylabel={RMSE},
        y tick label style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=2
        },
        legend style={at={(0.5,0.75)}, anchor=south east,  draw=none, fill=none},
        ]
        \addplot[mark=oplus*,blue] coordinates
        {(0.00,0.9397) (0.001, 0.9394) (0.002,0.9399) (0.003,0.9402) (0.004,0.9399)(0.005, 0.9400) (0.006,0.9406) (0.007,0.9405) (0.008,0.9408) 

        };
        \addlegendentry{Error}

        %       \addplot[mark=*,black] coordinates
        %       {     (2, 0.8780) (4,0.8569) (6,0.8428) (8,0.8326) (10,0.8249)(12, 0.8175) (14, 0.8114) (16,0.8063) (18,0.8010) (20,0.7950) (22,0.7909) (24,0.7860) (26,0.7821)
        %           (28,0.7780)(30,0.7737)(32,0.7700)(34,0.7655)(36,0.7615)(38,0.7587) (40,0.7548)(42,0.7510)(44,0.7481)(46,0.7442) (48,0.7405) (50,0.7372)
        %           
        %       };
        %       \addlegendentry{}

        \end{axis}

        \end{tikzpicture}


        \subcaption{Blabla}


    \end{subfigure}

    \caption{Performance}
    \label{tablex1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For the ticklabels see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9803/ (just do it for `x` instead of `y`). And `mark=o`.

Comment: Like this? `x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=4},`

Comment: It does not work :(

Comment: You need `scaled x ticks=false`, as mentioned in the first line of Jake's answer.

Comment: It did work. Thank you! Should I remove this post?

Comment: We can close as duplicate, that's more normal.